# Executar terminal a partir de programa Python

Tags: python, bash

Estou fazendo um trabalho de sistemas distribuídos, no qual estou utilizando PYRO, nele estou usando `objeto.adapter.rebindURI()` para utilizar o mesmo objeto quando o server que foi (derrubado) for "restartado"...

Estou querendo que esse *restart* seja a partir do meu programa Python... no caso pensei em chamar abrir uma nova janela e executar meu programa servidor...

Alguém sabe como fazer? Pois tentei N vezes e não consegui. Dá o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "serverApp.py", line 7, in <module>
>     subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 710, in __init__
>     errread, errwrite)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 1335, in _execute_child
>     raise child_exception
> OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
> ```

Eu tentei algo assim...

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["xterm"]

cmd.extend(['-e','bash','-c','python serverApp.py; exec $SHELL'])
```

Comment: Você tem o comando xterm instalado? O usuário que está executando o comando tem acesso a ele?

Comment: a ideia é um script que inicia um terminal e o mesmo execute um programa python ?.. ou apenas chamar o terminal

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente voce nao tem o xterm instalado em sua maquina.

Acredito que voce deve estar tentando dar um subprocess.call em cmd, o comando que seja executado sera:

`$ xterm -e bash -c python serverApp.py; exec $SHELL`

Tente executar isso em seu prompt de comando e provavelmente vera o mesmo problema.

Eu nao entendi porque voce iria executar o xterm antes. Tente executar o python diretamente e veja se o problema nao se resolve.

Ex:

`python> subprocess.call(['python', 'serverApp.py'])`

Answer (score 0):

Caso o xterm esteja instalado, a melhor forma de garantir sua execução é passar seu path absoluto no subprocess.

Para encontrar o caminho absoluto:

```
~ which xterm
/usr/bin/xterm
```

Incluir desta forma no Python Subprocess:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ["/usr/bin/xterm"]
```